# Autoplay HTML5 video on android (JS)

Tags: javascript, android, html

I know there are similar topics, but either they are outdated or with answers with JAVA code.

It seems android doesn't allow autoplay anymore and requires user gesture instead. Though, I want to make sure I exhaust all (reasonable) options before I stop trying.

The playback works perfectly on iOS and desktop.

Is there any way to have autoplay on android devices nowadays?

Video tag

```
<video
    muted="true"
    playsinline="true"
    loop="true"
    class="bg-video"
    autoplay="true"
>
    <source
        src="videos/low-android-480.mp4"
        class="bg-video-source"
        type="video/mp4" // Tried also without specifying the type
    />
</video>
```

– Hack to try and dispatch a user gesture **(doesn't work)**

```
const event = new MouseEvent("touchstart", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});

window.addEventListener("touchstart", function videoStart() {
    videoElement.play();
    // remove from the window and call the function we are removing
    window.removeEventListener("touchstart", videoStart);
}); 

...

if (videoElement.paused) {
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

– Simply calling `videoElement.play();` **(doesn't work)**

**UPDATE #1**
The hack example dispatchEvent part when modified like this

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

makes the video play on Android Chrome browser. Not on Native browser, though. Still searching a solution for that one...

**UPDATE #2**
Here is a useful snippet from the article mentioned in Jordi Castilla's answer. It allowed me to discover that the actual `videoElement.play()` promise gets rejected on Android Native browser.

```
    const promise = videoElement.play();

    if (promise !== undefined) {
        promise.then(_ => {
            // Autoplay started!
            alert("started autoplay");
        }).catch(error => {
            // Autoplay was prevented.
            alert("failed autoplay");
            // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since nobody else is answering, for people with a similar struggle the verdict is this:

- **You can't autoplay videos on Android native browsers**
- **You can't autoplay videos on iOS 9.x and lower**

Though, for Android Chrome browsers the **UPDATE #1** should be a guide on how to make autoplay work there.

Happy Coding!

*N.B. I would like someone to prove me wrong here*